# Python TypeError: unorderable types: builtin_function_or_method() < int()

Tags: python

I keep getting this error while trying to do a Python program. The point of the program is to keep on rolling a set of die, until the user enters a number less than 0.

```
import random

num_sixes = 0
num_sevens = 0
num_rolls = int(input('Enter number of rolls:\n'))

while (input <= 1):
    for i in range(num_rolls):
        die1 = random.randint(1,6)
        die2 = random.randint(1,6)
        roll_total = die1 + die2

    #Count number of sixes and sevens
    if roll_total == 6:
        num_sixes = num_sixes + 1
    if roll_total == 7:
        num_sevens = num_sevens + 1
    print('Roll %d is %d (%d + %d)' % (i, roll_total, die1, die2))

    print('\nDice roll statistics:')
    print('6s:', num_sixes)
    print('7s:', num_sevens)
else:
    print('Invalid number of rolls. Try again.')
```

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unorderable.py", line 7, in <module>
    while (input <= 1):
TypeError: unorderable types: builtin_function_or_method() <= int()
```

Comment: For indentation, the best way is to indent all your code in your editor before copypasting it.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing whether the built-in function `input` is less than or equal to 1

```
while (input <= 1):
```

Did you mean to do this instead?

```
while (num_rolls > 0):
```

Comment: Well that would explain it... Thanks for the help, next time I'll try desk checking a bit more...